# CakePHP 3 Display associated data in form

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

How can I show value instead of ID in below example?

Table Documents contain:
**id, title, body, person_id, review_date**
I get  like this, but not in DocumentsController (if it is important):

```
$test = $this->Documents->find('all',['conditions' => ['review_date'=>date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2022-01-01')) ] ]);
```

In .ctp it shows like this:

```
<tbody>
      <?php foreach ($test as $document): ?>
      <tr>
          <td><?= $document->id;  ?></td>
          <td><?= $document->person_id;  ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

And I want to display person's name instead of **person_id**.
All add function from the Controller:

```
   public function add()
    {
        $this->loadModel('Documents');
        $this->loadModel('Persons');
        $this->loadModel('SelfReports');
        $this->loadModel('PlannedQuestions');
        $agenda = $this->Agendas->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $agenda = $this->Agendas->patchEntity($agenda, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Agendas->save($agenda)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The agenda has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The agenda could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $per = $this->Persons->find('all');
        $tes = $this->Documents->find('all',[
            'conditions' => ['review_date'=>date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2022-01-01'))], 
        'fields' => ['Documents.id','RefArticles.article_number','Persons.name']]); 
        $selfreports = $this->SelfReports->find('all',['conditions' => ['next_visit_date'=> date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( 'thursday this week'))]]);
        $plannedquestions = $this->PlannedQuestions->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('agenda', 'tes'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['agenda']);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it myself...
I use this and it work's:
In Controller

```
$tes = $this->Documents->find('all',[
            'contain'=>['Persons'],
            'conditions' => ['review_date'=>date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2022-01-01'))]]);
```

And in .ctp

```
 <td><?= $document->person->surnamepat;  ?></td>
```